# Using searchkick with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, search, elasticsearch

I want use the searchkick gem, but I am trying to create a search where the results load as the user types.  Would it be possible to use AJAX to create a live search field? If so, what approach would I use doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do this with Rails and typeahead.js: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#autocomplete